# cross product proof - vector between 2 other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with a cross product proof and need help with getting it started.

A vector $\mathrm Z$ has an endpoint on a line between vectors $\mathrm P$ and $\mathrm Q$. Prove that:
$$
\mathrm Z \times (\mathrm P-\mathrm Q) = \mathrm P \times \mathrm Q.
$$

I assume I need to define $\mathrm Z$ in terms of $\mathrm P$ and $\mathrm Q$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Well if $Z$ is on the line segment between $P$ and $Q$ then you could write it as $Z=Q+a(P-Q)$ for some $a\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks,  that's what I needed to complete it